# Prove that $\mathbb{R}^2$ cannot be a subset of the union of a countable collection of lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, baire-category

I'm not really sure about this. I think the proof relies on the theorem: If $U$ is a subset of $A$, and $U$ is uncountable, then $A$ is uncountable.

The problem statement says a collection of lines is countable. $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not countable so $\mathbb{R}^2$ cant be a subset of a countable collection of lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Looks more like a topology question than set theory. Baire's theorem is pertinent.

Comment: A Lebesgue measure argument would work here...

Comment: I think this may simply be set theory.

Answer (score 7):

Consider the unit circle. Each line has at most two points in common with it, but the circle has uncountably many points.

Comment: this is nice ! We can flip it to show the plane is not the union of circles.

Comment: @TheKindCat I started writing things down with lines, but wanted to avoid the $y=mx+b$ vs. $x=c$ ramification - and ended up with the circle :)

Comment: This is far simpler and shorter than my argument. +1

Answer (score 2):

Let $\;L=\{\ell_i\}_{i\in I}\;,\;\;|I|\le \aleph_0\;$ , be a countable collection of lines in the plane, and let also

$$\;Y:=\left\{y\in\Bbb R\;:\; \exists i\in I\;\text{such that}\; (0,y)\in\ell_i\right\}\;$$

If $\;\;\bigcup\limits_{i\in I}\ell_i=\Bbb R^2\;$ then it must be that $\;Y=\mathcal Y:=\{(0,y)\;:\;\;y\in\Bbb R\}=\;$ the $\;y -$ axis , but this can't be since $\;|Y|\le\aleph_0\;$ whereas $\;|\mathcal Y|=2^{\aleph_0}=\mathfrak c :=\;$ the continuum cardinal.

Comment: I'm sorry, why is $Y$ countable? What if the $y$ axis *is* one of the lines in $L$?

Comment: I think it's clearer if you first pick $y_0$ so that $x=y_0$ is not one of the lines. But this is very nice nonetheless.

Comment: @Thekindcat It isn't a matter of clarity: The argument isn't even correct until you pick such an $x_0$.

Comment: Oh, I really didn't read the answer because of all of the quantifiers and stuff. But somehow I got the point.

Comment: @James Thank you. You are right, yet there are non-countable possible lines since there are non-countable possible slopes, so I think one can assume one of them is the usually vertical axis in the plane. If it is not then it can be any other but I think the argument stands firm. And I think $\;Y\;$, being defined by the index set $\;I\;$ , is countable.

Comment: @TheKindCat Thank you. What quantifiers? As far as I can see there's only one in my answer. Did you mean anything else?

Comment: @Joanperno Not quite. It can't "be any other" because, if you pick a particular line and declare that that line will always fail to be covered, you are incorrect, as, there are possible $L$s containing that line.

If you want the argument to work you have to do the following: As there are only countably many lines, there are only countably many vertical lines. As the $x$-axis is uncountable then, there is an $x_0$ so that the line $x = x_0$ is not in $L$. Then continue from there.

Comment: maybe not quantifiers, but mathy symbols.

Comment: @James Thank you. Fine, so do it with vertical lines. I think it doesn't matter that much whether it is a vertical one or not, but it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that one can also use the following argument:

Let if possible, $ \mathbb{R}^2 = \cup_{i \in I} L_i$ where $I$ is some countable set and $L_i$ denotes a line in the plane. Now compute the Lebesgue measure on both sides.
$$ 
m_2(\mathbb{R}^2) \leq \sum_{i} m_2(L_i) =0.
$$
A contradiction.